# mesurait de façon grotesque le temps

Tags: vocabulaire

Please explain "**mesurait de façon grotesque le temps**".
Thanks in advance.  --- tk

Le personnage ressorti de Colombey **mesurait de façon grotesque le temps** écoulé de l’enfance à aujourd'hui. ( *Les Années*, Annie Ernaux, page 71 )

Comment: In the English translation of the book, the sentence reads "The personage summoned from Colombey made it grotesquely clear how much time had passed since we were children," which is not anywhere close to how I would have translated it.

Comment: What word(s) don't you understand exactly? You have to consider two ideas in this sentence: 1) *Le personnage* (That's De Gaulle) *mesurait le temps écoulé de l’enfance à aujourd'hui*. 2) He did that (i.e. mesurer le temps) *de façon grotesque*.

Comment: @PeterShor I think the translation you're quoting is correct, just a little over explanatory.   "Summoned" makes it obvious that De Gaulle left Colombey in 1958 because he was asked to do so, whereas *ressorti* could imply leaving Colombey was the result of De Gaulle's own reflection. Maybe the translator wanted this over explanation because they thought some English readers would not have the historical background to understand.

Comment: @None: DeepL translator provides "The figure that emerged from Colombey was a grotesque measure of the time elapsed from childhood to the present day.," which illustrates how *mesurait de façon grotesque le temps* could mean *made it grotesquely clear*.

Comment: @None The translation goes too far, IMHO, and even maybe misleading: grotesque is only about how the measure is done, not anything about clear/clarity. _mesurait de façon grotesque_ does not leave much room to change that _grotesque_ refers to _mesurer_.

Comment: I also don't understand the intention of the author when he used the word "grotesque" to qualify the way of measuring elapsed time. This word has the same meaning in both English and French, i.e. ridiculous, clownish.

Comment: @Graffito: Elapsed time is being measured here by observing the transformation of de Gaulle from a handsome man into an old, fat, ugly man with a tremulous voice. I think this at least comes close to qualifying as *grotesque*.

Comment: @Graffito Because of its negative connotations, _grotesque_ seems to introduce some sort of criticism of De Gaulle. I think that's where more context would be useful. Peter's observation is possible, but I'm wondering if there isn't more, for example, a criticism that De Gaulle is measuring time as some sort of excuse that Annie Ernaux finds unacceptable somehow. Again, we would need more context here.

Comment: @Frank: As much of the context as I can find online: *Nous qui avions le souvenir d’un visage sec sous un képi, petite moustache d’avant-guerre, sur les affiches de la ville en ruine, qui n’avions pas entendu l’appel du 18 juin, étions ahuris et déçus par ces joues pendantes et ces sourcils broussailleux de notaire engraissé, cette voix parasitée par un tremblement de vieux. Le personnage ressorti de Colombey mesurait de façon grotesque le temps écoulé de l’enfance à aujourd’hui.* But from the English translation, there's not much more context than that.

Comment: From the context given by @PeterShor, another formulation of the sentence could be *L'aspect du personnage ressorti de Colombey donnait de façon grotesque la mesure du temps écoulé de l’enfance à aujourd’hui* (The aspect of the personage summoned from Colombey made  grotesquely evident how much time had passed since we were children)

Comment: @PeterShor Vu le contexte, ce qui est _grotesque_, c'est l'état physique du vieux De Gaulle, et cet état _mesure_ le temps écoulé... Le fait que son état est maintenant grotesque donne une mesure de combien de temps s'est écoulé. On se rend compte de combien de temps s'est vraiment écoulé en voyant son aspect maintenant grotesque. Son état grotesque est une façon de mesurer le temps.